# Deoptim optimizer for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization

I have been looking for a multi-core optimizer for Python thats equivalent to DEopt.

Been messing around with https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt but mutli-core support is very lacking.

Does anyone know of any good alternatives that support using multiple cores?

Answer (score 4):

Check out Ray Tune - it supports multi-core along with distributed executions of random search, grid search, and evolutionary methods (specifically Population-Based Training), which seems to be what you're looking for.

Here's the docs page - [ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tune.html](http://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tune.html)

Disclaimer: I work on this project!

Answer (score 1):

Have been using hyperopt, its a direct replacement for deoptim for python.

https://github.com/hyperopt/hyperopt